# react redux store is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  router: routerStateReducer,
  todos,
})

const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  reduxReactRouter({ routes, createHistory })
  )(createStore)(reducer);


export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState)
```

It is giving me `createStoreWithMiddleware` is not a function.. Why this ?

Comment: try using let, as opposed to const, and please let me know if the error changes for you

Comment: sorry no change.. I think the issue is somewhere else.. `react-redux` documentation has not pointed this out..

Comment: Updated with solution

Comment: don't update the question with the answer :/ now we don't know if something is wrong or not. could you revert the changes and post an explained answer?

Comment: Yes, do not just overwrite the question with the answer as that will be more confusing to anyone in the future who looks at this post. Either edit your post with the solution *below* the faulty code or make an actual answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing the result of `compose` (which returns a function). So instead of setting `createStoreWithMiddleware` to the returned function, you are setting it to the executed result with the variable `reducer`.

Not sure what the variable `reducer` in this context is since you have `rootReducer` defined above. Your code should probably read:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  reduxReactRouter({ routes, createHistory })
)(createStore)
```

doing so will define `createStoreWithMiddleware` as an extended `createStore` function, which can then receive your `rootReducer` and `initialState`.